# How to obtain value of select box in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, tags, document, devextreme

Im trying to obtain a value from a selectbox but I cant ,

Inspector shows me:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/16MZx.png

I tried 2 ways (code below), but I dont know how to get final value

In this case; "Activo"

```
        //way1
        var way1 = document.getElementById("Patrimonio");
        console.log(way1);
        //way2
        var way2 = document.getElementsByClassName("dx-placeholder");
        console.log(way2);
```

I expect obtain that value, to store in a javascript variable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get selected value in dropdown list using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085801/get-selected-value-in-dropdown-list-using-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#Patrimonio").dxSelectBox('instance').option('value')
```

Comment: First:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'undefined' of undefined

Sencond:
VM171:324 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Comment: with jquery try this, $("#Patrimonio").dxSelectBox('instance').option('value')

Comment: var way2 = $("#Patrimonio").dxSelectBox('instance').option('value');  works!! thanks!